# Launch python script in .desktop without root privileges

Tags: raspbian, python

I've made a script on My Raspberry Pi (Rasbian Jessie) where I made a .desktop file to launch a Python script from the desktop.

When I open nautilus and go to the desktop path, the file runs. But when I double-click it from the desktop (without root privileges) nothing happens.

**Shortcut.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Network Monitor
Comment=This is my comment
Exec=python /home/Network_Monitor_Device/Scripts/Interface.py
Icon=/home/Network_Monitor_Device/Scripts/Logo.PNG
Path=/home/Network_Monitor_Device/Scripts/
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
StartupNotify=true
```

**Interface.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sqlite3
import subprocess
import sys
...
```

**Permissions on .desktop**

[image]

Comment: The problem was that the permission of Network_Monitor_Device was root. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found the solution:**

The permission of folder "Network_Monitor_Device" was still on root. I've changed it to "Pi" and the script did it!